# Get latest record in each group - mysql (by max date/max primary key)

Tags: mysql

| id | orderid | assignedto | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2001 | 1400 | 11, June 2020 |
| 102 | 2001 | 1560 | 16, June 2021 |
| 103 | 3450 | 1560 | 19, June 2020 |

Desired result -

| id | orderid | assignedto | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 2001 | 1560 | 16, June 2021 |
| 103 | 3450 | 1560 | 19, June 2020 |

For each order id I want the last person who was assigned to the order.

My current query retrieves data by joining other fields as -

```
select y.id, x.orderid, assigneedto, date from (select id, orderid, date as date_rejected 
from tbl1
where status = 'A') x 
left join tbl1 as y
on x.orderid = y.orderid 
where y.status = 'B' and x.date_rejected > y.date
```

I tried using **max(date)** and **grouping by orderid** but the results are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It's very complicated to understand what do you mean as tables are different from query, but I guess OVER PARTITION BY function will definitely resolve your issue, even without left join.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html